# mysql query to mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello pls I want migrate the following code to mysqli. Pls help out, it's login functions. The first function gets the `user_id` from the database while the  second function check if the `username` and `password` match for that user from the `user_id`.

```
function user_id_from_usernam­e($username){
   $username = sanitize($username);
   return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}

function login($username, $password){
  $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
  $username = sanitize($username);
  $password = md5($password);
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
  return  ( mysql_result($query­, 0) == 1)? $user_id : false;
}
```

Comment: please avoid mysql_* function as these are now deprecated in php 7

Comment: php version pls sepcify ?

Comment: format it properly please

Comment: And while you're at it, use `mysqli::prepare()` instead of `query()`. And use proper password hashing algorithms, `md5()` isn't safe anymore. And **formatting your code** makes it all the much easier to read and troubleshoot!

Comment: @Learner php 5+

Comment: You just wanna change the query from mysql to mysqli?

Comment: When ever you ask a question, you should at least post some readable code and not such a mess. Why should someone take the time to give you an answer if you don't take the time to format your code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like MD5**.

Answer (score 0):

The correct query form for the mysqli_query is :

```
mysqli_query($connection_variable,"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
```